# Cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations

Error : PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
LINE 1: ..._at" timestamp, "total" decimal DEFAULT (COALESCE(price, (0)...

```
class AddTotalToOrderLines < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
def up
  execute <<~SQL
    ALTER TABLE order_lines
    ADD COLUMN total numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(price, 0) * 
    COALESCE(quantity, 0)) STORED;
  SQL
end
```

Comment: Your error message mentions a `default` clause but your code creates a generated column - those two pieces don't fit together (unless Ruby changes the `generated always` to `default`)

Answer (score 1):

In case you thought you were going crazy (or some googler finds this), the issue is Rails converts a `GENERATED` column statement to a `DEFAULT` one if you're using `schema.rb`.  In order to get it to behave you need to switch over to the `structure.sql` approach.

Comment: Rails 7 added support for GENERATED columns https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/01/25/rails-7-postgres-support-for-generated-columns/

Comment: @BrunoDegomme Does that change the stated behaviour? i.e. would the migration in the OP create a correct `schema.rb` entry in Rails 7?

Comment: yes, it can be rewritten as `add_column :order_lines, :total, :numeric, virtual: true, as: "(COALESCE(price, 0) * COALESCE(quantity, 0))", stored: true`, and will appear in schema.rb as 
`t.virtual "total", type: :numeric, as: "(COALESCE(price, 0) * COALESCE(quantity, 0))", stored: true`. It can even be used in Rails 6 using this gem https://github.com/retailzipline/pg_generated_column_support

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have another migration that's actually generating the error.  The one you're showing there isn't :)